# Are the HD video version from iTunes necessary if only watching from iPhone?

Tags: iphone, itunes

I have a subscription to the TV show Mad Men and each week iTunes sends me both the HD and standard versions but I only watch them on my iPhone is it safe to delete the HD versions as they seem to be only good for taking up room on my disk drive or am I missing something?

Comment: ... aaand breath

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can safely delete them if you don't watch them on the computer. But the HD episodes cost more than the SD ones, so when you buy them, buy the SD version if available.